# Vue.js + Firebase update chat message box after sending

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I'm starting with vue.js and firebase and I have a chat system using firebase. I get all the users’ id that have sent messages to me. So in my database I get their data and list with a `v-for`.

After listing them I get their messages from FB to list in a message box below each user.

Everything is working fine but I cannot get sent messages instantly after sending them.

I made a workaround with `push()` to append each sent message to data property but I'd like to know if there is a better way to do that with vue.js.

I've tested with plain javascript (separately with one message box) and the chat is updated on every sent message.

Is there a way to make this work without replacing all data object or calling all the listing process again? I tried with Vue's Reactivity but I could not make it work as expected.

```
<div v-if="isLoading == true" id="loading"><img class="loading" src="../assets/img/loading.gif" /></div>

<div v-if="isLoading == false" class="row messages-row" v-for="(item, index) in memberData" :key="index">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
        <div class="messages-profile-infos">
            <div class="messages-profile-infos-img img-fluid" v-bind:style="{'background-image': 'url(http://localhost/backend/imgs/'+item.memberProfileImg + ')' }"></div>
            <div class="messages-profile-infos-text">
                <p>{{ item.memberName }} {{ item.memberLastname }}</p>
                <p>{{ item.memberCity }} - {{ item.memberState }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-12">
        <div class="messages-btns">
            <button class="btn trade-btn" @click="showConversation(item.memberID)">Messages</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
        <div class="messages-status">
            <a class="btn border btn-circle text-uppercase confirm-service-btn" href="javascript:void(0);">
                Confirm
            </a>
            <a class="btn border btn-circle text-uppercase cancel-service-btn" href="javascript:void(0);">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- conversation box -->
    <div v-if="memberBox == item.memberID" class="conversation-container" :id="item.memberID">
        <div v-for="(tour, index) in item.tours" :key="index" id="tourOnConversation" class="tourOnConversation">
            <span>Tour:</span>
            <span><strong>{{ tour.title }}</strong></span>
        </div>
        <div id="messages-container" class="messages-container" :key="item.memberID">
            <div v-for="message in item.messages" class="d-flex" :class="[message.uid != myID ?'justify-content-start':'justify-content-end']">
                <span class="badge badge-pill" :class="[message.uid != myID ?'badge-primary':'badge-secondary']">{{ message.message }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="message-typing-container">
            <form id="messages_form" action="" method="POST">
                <div class="typing-container">
                    <input id="message" v-model="messages" type="text" class="message-typing" autocomplete="off" />
                    <input class="send-message" type="submit" value="Send" @click="sendMessage(item.memberID, item.tour)" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
</div>
```

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

let app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
        return {
            memberData: {},
            myMessages: [],
            memberMessages: [],
            myID: userID,
            messages: "",
            messageBox: 0,
            conversation: {},
            isLoading: true,
            memberBox: 0,
        };
    },
    created: function () {
        this.getAllMessages();
    },
    methods: {
        scrollBox: function () {
            let messagebox = document.querySelector("#messages-container");
            messagebox.scrollTop = messagebox.scrollHeight;
        },
        getAllMessages: function () {
          
            let distinct = "";

            firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection("messages")
                .where("memberID", "==", `${this.myID}`)
                .orderBy("date")
                .onSnapshot((res) => {
                    let members = [];
                    res.forEach((doc) => {
                        members.push(doc.data().uid);
                    });
              
                    distinct = Array.from(new Set(members));
                    this.getUserToTalk(distinct);
                });
        },
        getMyMessages: function (memberID) {
            let myMessages = [];
            firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection("messages")
                .where("uid", "==", `${this.myID}`)
                .where("memberID", "==", `${memberID}`)
                .orderBy("date")
                .onSnapshot((res) => {
                    res.forEach((doc) => {
                        myMessages.push(doc.data());
                    });
                });
          
            return myMessages;
        },
        getMessages: function (memberID) {
            let messages = [];
            firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection("messages")
                .where("uid", "==", `${memberID}`)
                .where("memberID", "==", `${this.myID}`)
                .orderBy("date")
                .onSnapshot((res) => {
                    res.forEach((doc) => {
                        messages.push(doc.data());
                    });
                });
          
            return messages;
        },
        getUserToTalk: function (memberID) {
            axios
                .post("http://localhost/backend/getMemberToTalk.php", {
                    token: token,
                    whoToTalkTo: memberID,
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    // console.log(response.data);
                    if (response.data != "Error receiving data") {
                        let joinedData = [];

                        response.data.forEach((res) => {
                            let messages = this.getMessages(res.memberID);
                            let myMessages = this.getMyMessages(res.memberID);
                            // console.log(messages);
                            // console.log(myMessages);

                            let conversation = [];
                            let data = {};

                            setTimeout(() => {
                                conversation = [...messages, ...myMessages];

                                conversation.sort(function (a, b) {
                                    return a.date - b.date;
                                });
                                // console.log(conversation);

                                if (conversation.length > 0) {
                                    data = {
                                        memberID: res.memberID,
                                        memberProfileImg: res.memberProfileImg,
                                        memberName: res.memberName,
                                        memberLastname: res.memberLastname,
                                        memberCity: res.memberCity,
                                        memberState: res.memberState,
                                        messages: conversation,
                                        tour: conversation[0].tour,
                                    };
                                    this.isLoading = false;
                                } else {
                                    this.isLoading = true;
                                    this.getAllMessages();
                                }

                                joinedData.push(data);
                            }, 2000);
                        });
                        // console.log(joinedData);

                        this.memberData = joinedData;
                        console.log(this.memberData);
                    } else {
                        console.log(response.data);
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },
        sendMessage: function (memberID, tourID) {
            $("#messages_form").on("submit", (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();

                let message = this.messages;
                if (!message.trim()) return;

                let postmessage = {
                    uid: JSON.stringify(this.myID),
                    memberID: JSON.stringify(memberID),
                    message: message,
                    date: Date.now(),
                    tour: "2",
                };

                // console.log(message);
                this.messages = "";

                this.memberData.forEach((res) => {
                    console.log(res.messages);
                    if (memberID == res.memberID) res.messages.push(postmessage);
                });

                console.log(this.memberData);

                firebase.firestore().collection('messages').add({
                    uid: JSON.stringify(this.myID),
                    memberID: JSON.stringify(memberID),
                    message: message,
                    date: Date.now(),
                    tour: tourID
                }).then(res => {
                     // console.log('Message sent: ' + res.message);

                }).catch(e => console.log(e));
            });
        },
        showConversation: function (memberID) {
            // console.log(memberID);
            // let id = $('.conversation-container').attr('id');
            this.memberBox = memberID;
            if (this.memberBox == memberID) {
                $(".conversation-container").toggle("fast");
            }
        },
    },
    mounted() {},
});
```

Comment: First, you should drop jquery. For example `$("#messages_form").on("submit")` can be replaced with `@submit.prevent="onSubmit(item)"` property on element or even better call it on button instead of form when there is only one input. Then you can do `item.push(postmessage)` without loop. Check vue doc about events.